# How to use nested lookup in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Was facing difficulties in using nested lookups for many-to-many field in django.

Please find code snippet below :

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type,related_name="tags_college",null=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Query(models.Model):
    query = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags,related_name="query_tags")
```

Need to make a query on Query table where all tag in many-to-many field of query table must have tags with type attribute equal to null .

Answer (score 2):

```
null_type_tags = Tags.objects.filter(type__isnull=True)
queries = Query.objects.filter(tags__in=null_type_tags)
```

but untested..

Side Note: You better rename your models, these may shadow the preserved names..

Comment: This is very costly operation , every time an api will be hit i will have to filter tags whose type is null , what if i have more than 10 lakh tags objects.

Comment: These are [lazy query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), so it shouldn't reduce performance.